# centring an image in a frame

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, shift

I am trying to centre an image in a frame as shown below. I am using openCV and C. I searched for linear transformations and shifting functions in openCV but got nothing so far. Would anyone be able to advise me as to which functions to use in order to achieve the effect in the 2nd image? I would greatly appreciate it.[image: video frame both before and after centring]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at **transform**?

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/operations_on_arrays.html#transform

> Transform(src, dst, transmat, shiftvec=NULL) → None¶

```
Performs matrix transformation of every array element.
Parameters: 

    src (CvArr) – The first source array
    dst (CvArr) – The destination array
    transmat (CvMat) – Transformation matrix
    shiftvec (CvMat) – Optional shift vector
```

Comment: thank you very much. Can you include this or code it please? I do not know exactly how to code the transmat and shiftvec parts